# What is the procedure on upgrading React 15.X to React 16.X

Tags: reactjs

I upgraded from React 15.X to 16.X, but there are so many methods are no longer used, that result the application can’t work as expected. But the application linked with LOTS of old libraries which relay on 15.X. Is this possible to have both React version in the same application? Thanks.

Comment: The react app itself should work, but the problem you most likely have is with the dependencies. Check whether they are all compatible with React 16. When I upgraded I had to drop a few packages, hopefully they will be upgraded eventually.

Answer (score 15):

You'll have to explicitly tell npm to go to the next major version.

```
npm install --save react@^16.0.0 react-dom@^16.0.0
```

then run

```
npm update --save
```

to get all dependent packages and latest updates for all your packages.

Comment: running `npm update --save` after updating react to specific @16.4.0 updated react to the latest version. Undoing the first step. Have run @16.4.0 again but fear a load of other packages will have been updated to match latest version of react after the `npm update --save`.

Answer (score 4):

From [React v16.0 Blog Post](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/26/react-v16.0.html):

> ... With minor exceptions, if your app runs in 15.6 without any warnings,
>   it should work in 16.
>
> For deprecations listed in packaging below, codemods are provided to
>   automatically transform your deprecated code. See the 15.5.0 blog post
>   for more information, or browse the codemods in the react-codemod
>   project.

Maybe check the [react-codemod](https://github.com/reactjs/react-codemod) project out?