# compilation error when upgraded from ReactJS 15 + webpack 3.x TO ReactJS 16 + webpack 4

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

my app currently working fine with ReactJS 15 however I thought of upgrading it to ReactJS 16, currently I have an app which has both client and Server part.

many files are being referred in both client and server side, to upgrade ReactJS 16, I created a new project using create-react-app command , then I copied all my files/folders from old project to new project.

when I compiled, I faced lot of issues with respect to import / require style of including files , all the js files using module.exports = kind of are not working at all with ReactJS 16.

now I am getting following error, for which I am not getting any help in internet.

```
Failed to compile.

  Error: Child compilation failed:
  SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

  - Function

  - lodash.js:14866 
    [myapp]/[lodash]/lodash.js:14866:16

  - lodash.js:473 apply
    [myapp]/[lodash]/lodash.js:473:27

  - lodash.js:15250 
    [myapp]/[lodash]/lodash.js:15250:16

  - lodash.js:475 apply
    [myapp]/[lodash]/lodash.js:475:27

  - lodash.js:6569 
    [myapp]/[lodash]/lodash.js:6569:16

  - lodash.js:14865 Function.template
    [myapp]/[lodash]/lodash.js:14865:20

  - SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

  - compiler.js:141 childCompiler.runAsChild
    [myapp]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/compiler.js:141:18

  - Compiler.js:306 compile
    [myapp]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:306:11

  - Compiler.js:630 hooks.afterCompile.callAsync.err
    [myapp]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:630:14

  - Hook.js:154 AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook
    [myapp]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20

  - Compiler.js:627 compilation.seal.err
    [myapp]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:627:30

  - Hook.js:154 AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook
    [myapp]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20

  - Compilation.js:1325 hooks.optimizeAssets.callAsync.err
    [myapp]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1325:35

  - Hook.js:154 AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook
    [myapp]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20

  - Compilation.js:1316 hooks.optimizeChunkAssets.callAsync.err
    [myapp]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1316:32

  - Hook.js:154 AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook
    [myapp]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20

  - Compilation.js:1311 hooks.additionalAssets.callAsync.err
    [myapp]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1311:36
```

Comment: You need to delete `node_modules` folder and manually insert all your dependencies in `package.json` file and then try `npm install`

Comment: Try npm install dude

Comment: @ravibagul91  hi I have already did it many times, all modules are installed

Comment: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47244506/what-is-the-procedure-on-upgrading-react-15-x-to-react-16-x